# Finding the upper and lower bound by using substitution-method. (Algorithme)

Tags: algorithm

I need some help in substitution method in Algorithm And Data Structure. I am a first year student and at this moment,  I have started a course called Algorithm And Data Structure.
My Task is posted in the following:
I have read my book many times, but the book confuses me even worse.
Is there  who wants to help me in solving this task.
For instance task one.:
There is given a function:
p(n)=p(n/2)+p(n/3)+n and I'm asked to find both the upper and lower bound.
How do I guess a form for the solution? (Sorry that question seems so silly)

The Task can be be read in the following:

The CPS Brewing Company (CPSBC) has a wide selection of beers, and every
time they introduce a new one they always sell it for cheap.
 The next year they
up the price a bit, and again the following year, and so on. In this devious
pricing scheme the price of a beer in 2015 may depend on the price of that same
beer in the previous years. Your goal is to figure out the asymptotic behaviour
of the price of different beers. We denote the price of a beer the year it’s
introduced and the following years by p(1), p(2) ,.........., respectively.
The CPC (Chief Price Consultant) of CPSBC then decides on a recursive formula (called a pricing
scheme) – for instance the price of CPSBC’s world famous USB-Porter is given
by:  p(n)=2p(n/2)+n.

We know from CLRS that this asymptotically behaves
as: p(n)=O(n*log(n)).
Your task is to give an asymptotic upper bound for p(n) for each of the
following pricing schemes. You should make your bound as tight as possible.

Task 1: For the following pricing schemes, use the substitution method. Remember to give both the upper and lower bounds. Be careful to avoid the
pitfalls of the substitution method (see CLRS, page 86).
Additionally, you also have to draw a recursion tree down to at least four
levels for one of the recurrences.

1. p(n)=p(n/2)+p(n/3)+n .
2. p(n)=sqrt(n)* p(sqrt(n))+ sqrt(n)

Is anyone out there who wants to guide or help me in solving this task.

Thank you in advance, Sara_D

Comment: a good place to start is http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/analysis-algorithm-set-4-master-method-solving-recurrences/ ...

Comment: What do **you** think? What did you try already? Give us your initial tryout, as "bad" as you think it is.

Comment: I have thought that p(n) less or equal to c*n*logn(n) for the upper bound and otherwise for the lower bound, but I come out with no conlussion.

Comment: Any guess I do comes out wrong.